# Memory Leak Issue in Apache POI 3.9 version

Tags: memory-leaks, apache-poi, xlsx, temporary-files, xssf

I have used Apache POI for creating .xlsx files. I tried with POI 3.8 version but it has the memory leakage issue(It creates temp files and take large amount of time to create excel file). Now I am using POI 3.9 version, but it also shows the memory leakage issue same as in 3.8 version. I tried to retrieve 10000 records from DB and creates Excel file, It took around one hour time to create the file. **

**Is there any new function or new package available in 3.9 version for resolving the memory leakage issue??**

Comment: What do you mean by "memory leakage"? Do you just mean it uses lots of memory? As for the slow creation, have you tried profiling to ensure the delay really is in POI, and not in your own code?

Comment: It creates temporary xml files and increasing the size of this file while running the program. What is profiling, am not aware of it. Can you please explain?

Comment: @CTcreations: Please check this http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html to understand profiling.(Hope you are using ecllipse)